# Lufthansa APIS form, visa issuing country

Tags: visas, usa

My US visa was issued in US embassy in Croatia, what should I enter as Issuing country and Country for which visa applies for APIS. Is it USA or Croatia.
[image]

Comment: A US embassy (or really, any foreign embassy) is considered sovereign. So no matter where you are in the world, if the US embassy issued it, then the issuing country is the US, and of course the visa is valid for the US.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Most commonly** "issuing country" and "country for which visa applies" are the same. In your case both should be USA.

When there are two different fields, it must be because some countries have cooperation agreements that allow country A to issue visas on country B's behalf to people who live in a location where A has a consulate but B doesn't.

Perhaps it also allows entering things such as "issuing country" being Germany and "country for which visa applies" being all the Schengen states.

Answer (score 1):

Visa applies for the USA and was issued by the USA.